# NodeJS - SMPP not sending

Tags: node.js, smpp

I'm trying to send an SMS messaging using [node-smpp](https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp) along with the [ActiveXperts free demo service](http://www.activexperts.com/sms-messaging-server/gateway/).

Here's what the ActiveXperts documentation says to send a free demo message:

[image]

As per the [node-smpp documentation](https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp), here's my code:

```
var smpp = require('smpp');
var session = smpp.connect('smpp.activexperts-labs.com', 2775);
session.bind_transceiver({}, function(pdu) {
    console.log(pdu);
    if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
        // Successfully bound
        session.submit_sm({
            destination_addr: '1234567890',
            short_message: 'Hello!'
        }, function(pdu) {
            if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
                // Message successfully sent
                console.log(pdu.message_id);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And here is my PDU response:

```
PDU {
  command_length: 32,
  command_id: 2147483657,
  command_status: 14,
  sequence_number: 1,
  command: 'bind_transceiver_resp',
  system_id: 'ActiveXperts GW' }
```

The function that sends the message (`session.submit_sm`) is obviously not being called because the pdu results `command_status` = 14 instead of which the if statement requires, `if (pdu.command_status == 0)`.

I've removed the if statement and the message still doesn't send. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: which version of smpp you are using?

Comment: @JohnAnkanna I ran npm install npm --save and because of that I'm using version "0.2.0"

Comment: you are using the `SMPP v5.0 in node.js, with support for custom commands and TLVs.` which is not supporting  your `active experts free demo service`

Comment: is there a previous version I can use? or does SMPP just not support what I'm trying to do?

Comment: check this link https://www.versioneye.com/nodejs/smpp/0.0.3 you can download the old version one and be sure to check any syntax changes and response code and all

Comment: Ok thanks, will do! Would you be able to tell me what exactly is it about the current version that doesn't support active experts free demo service? I was contemplating purchasing this product & service, but if it doesn't work with the current version of SMPP I will have to reconsider

Answer (score 0):

In your code you passed an empty object as parameters for bind_transceiver method. You need to pass smpp credentials as follows:

```
session.bind_transceiver({
  system_id: 'YOUR_SYSTEM_ID',
  password: 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
}, function(pdu) {
```